# Dynamically Add Rows to Entry Form - Access 2010

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm building a database to track usage/generate reports of particular products on a daily basis.  There is a limited number of products (about 20) where they're removed from inventory, used in production, and then remaining product is returned to inventory but not put back into the system.  The idea is to have production record how much they receive and then have storage record how much they get back from production.

The tables are pretty straightforward - I have one table with product properties that I completely control for the foreseeable future and another that will house usage data.  The issue I'm having is how to design the form for operations for when they receive product.  I don't want to have a huge list of product #'s with entries for each one (usually 5 to 10 are used on a daily basis).  I also don't want to populate the data table with a bunch of blank records.  I want them to add a line, select the product code from a drop down, record the amount received and then repeat.  Preferably the drop down would update to exclude any previously filled in codes on the form.  I want to do this all at once to limit duplicate records.  So they fill out all the product #'s they received and how many of each they received and then click save to have it populate the data table.

Is there a way to have an "add line" option for a form of this design?  I know this isn't a terribly extensive database but I want to design and test it prior to integration into our plant's larger scale product tracking system.

Comment: What you describe is how a normal bound form works. It always has only one open line for a new entry. When a new entry has been entered and saved, a new empty line is added.

Comment: Several options each using a subform (other methods available also): (1) button click adds record to subform, user updates fields; have code to prevent closing form if user omits required info; (2) have subform linked to a temp table and you add as many product records as needed. When finished, add to primary table (code to clear table when finished); variation is to prompt user for how many products to add, then use code to add that # of records. This can be as simple or as complicated as you desire.